initialization of state variables when component renders & custom hooks
I have a component Body.jsx, it contained logic of fetching data from an API and filtering as well.
I tried to create a custom hook useResData which separates out logic of fetching data as shown-
export const Body = () => {
  const resDataList = useResData();

  const [filteredList, setFiltererdList] = useState(resDataList);
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState('');

  const filterList = () => {
    let filteredList = resDataList.filter((item) => item.info.avgRating > 4);
    setFiltererdList(filteredList);
  }

  if (resDataList.length === 0) return <Shimmer />;
        
  return (
    <div className="Body"> 
      <div className="search">
        <input
          className="search-input"
          value={inputText}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setInputText(e.target.value)
          }}
        />
        <button
          className="search-btn" 
          onClick={() => {
            let list = resDataList.filter((data) => data.info.name.toLowerCase().includes(inputText))
            setFiltererdList(list);
          }}
        >
          Search
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="filter-btn">
        <button onClick={filterList}>Top Rated Restaurants</button>
      </div>
      <div className="cardContainer">
        {filteredList.map((item) =>
          <Link
            to={'restaurants/' + item.info.id}
            key={item.info.id}
          >
            <Card resData={item?.info} key={item.info.id} />
          </Link>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

And custom hook is -
const useResData = () => {
  const [resDataList, setResDataList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getData = async () => {
      let res = await fetch(
        "https://www.swiggy.com/dapi/restaurants/list/v5?lat=28.65200&lng=77.16630&is-seo-homepage-enabled=true&page_type=DESKTOP_WEB_LISTING"
      );
      let data = await res.json();
      setResDataList(data?.data?.cards?.[4]?.card?.card?.gridElements?.infoWithStyle?.restaurants)
    }
    getData();
  }, [])

  return resDataList;
}

export default useResData;

Now the issue is when resDataList is populated in Body.tsx, it does not populate filteredList. I know that for filteredList to be populated I need to use setFiltererdList, but I read somewhere that each time a component renders it creates a separate copy of state variable, by this logic const [filteredList, setFiltererdList] = useState(resDataList); should initialize filteredList with resDataList each time Body component is rendered.

Since the filtering is not heavy, you can store it in a regular variable, which will be evaluated each run.

The initial value of useState is only used on the first render, at which point resDataList is still empty.
You could instead store a filter in the state and avoid redundant state by directly computing the filtered result during rendering.
const [filter, setFilter] = useState(() => () => true);
const filteredList = resDataList.filter(filter);

const filterList= () => setFilter(() => item => item.info.avgRating > 4);
// and so on



Now the issue is when resDataList is populated in Body.tsx, it does
not populate filteredList.

This is because the useEffect hook runs at the end of the render cycle, so the Body component was passed the initial, unpopulated resDataList state value which is the empty array.

I read somewhere that each time a component renders it creates a
separate copy of state variable, by this logic const [filteredList, setFiltererdList] = useState(resDataList); should initialize
filteredList with resDataList each time Body component is
rendered.

This is not true. React components mount and the state is initialized exactly once, and the arg passed to the useState hook is ignored after the initial render. After that it's up to the component to update and maintain its own state as necessary.
The trivial solution is to use a useEffect hook with a dependency on the returned resDataList value and enqueue state updates to synchronize the local filteredList state.
Example:
const resDataList = useResData();

const [filteredList, setFiltererdList] = useState(resDataList);

useEffect(() => {
  setFilteredList(resDataList);
}, [resDataList]);

Be aware that as-is this is a general React anti-pattern and should be avoided, e.g. copying the derived filtered value from the "useResData" state into Body. Just about any time you catch yourself having coded a useState-useEffect couplet you should actually use the useMemo hook to compute and provide a memoized/stable derived/computed value to the component.
Instead of waiting for the user to click a button to filter the results, just compute and return the correct data to be rendered. Use the inputText to also filter further inline when rendering, or if you feel this is computationally expensive, you can just include this in the memoization.
const resDataList = useResData();

const filteredList = useMemo(() => {
  return resDataList.filter((item) => item.info.avgRating > 4);
}, [resDataList]);

export const Body = () => {
  const resDataList = useResData();

  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState('');

  const filteredList = useMemo(() => {
    return resDataList.filter((item) => item.info.avgRating > 4);
  }, [resDataList]);

  if (!resDataList.length) return <Shimmer />;
        
  return (
    <div className="Body"> 
      <div className="search">
        <input
          className="search-input"
          value={inputText}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setInputText(e.target.value)
          }}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="cardContainer">
        {filteredList
          .filter(
            item => item.info.name.toLowerCase().includes(
              inputText.toLowerCase()
            ))
          )
          .map((item) => (
            <Link
              key={item.info.id}
              to={'restaurants/' + item.info.id}
            >
              <Card resData={item?.info} key={item.info.id} />
            </Link>
          ))
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

or
export const Body = () => {
  const resDataList = useResData();

  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState('');

  const filteredList = useMemo(() => {
    return resDataList.filter((item) => {
      const { info: { avgRating, name } } = item;
      return avgRating > 4 && name.toLowerCase().includes(
        inputText.toLowerCase()
      ));
    });
  }, [inputText, resDataList]);

  if (!resDataList.length) return <Shimmer />;
        
  return (
    <div className="Body"> 
      <div className="search">
        <input
          className="search-input"
          value={inputText}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setInputText(e.target.value)
          }}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="cardContainer">
        {filteredList.map((item) => (
          <Link
            key={item.info.id}
            to={'restaurants/' + item.info.id}
          >
            <Card key={item.info.id} resData={item.info} />
          </Link>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}


This is not true. React components mount and the state is initialized exactly once. After that it's up to the component to update and maintain its own state as necessary. then how come we update a 'const' value? state variable is initialized as const, still we are able to update it throught state setter functions, but this is contradictory to the fact that const values can never be modified.
Isn't this because on each render that 'const' state variable is not modified instead its a  new variable all together and initialized with updated state value?

@meg In Javascript a variable being declared const only means it can't be re-assigned a new value, but they can certainly be modified/mutated though. You could also declare your React state with let or (shudders) var if you wanted, React doesn't care. I think the part you are not understanding is that the initial arg passed to the useState hook is only used for the initial render cycle, it's ignored on all subsequent render cycles. See useState parameters.

@meg "then how come we update a 'const' value? state variable is initialized as const, still we are able to update it throught state setter functions, but this is contradictory to the fact that const values can never be modified." - This is because you are not modifying or re-assigning it during a render, your React function is called again and the current state value is assigned to the const variable in the function body. It's not contradictory to anything.

@meg "Isn't this because on each render that 'const' state variable is not modified instead its a new variable all together and initialized with updated state value?" - Basically, yes. This all fits within my answer's statements that the state is initialized once, and you enqueue state updates to update the value, e.g. what the const variable in the function body of the next render cycle will be. This part of my answer was pointing out your misunderstanding that the value passed to useState is used each time. resDataList is used only once on the first render cycle.
